# Handwriting recognition as in Webapp

Tags: web, web-applications, handwriting-recognition

I was wondering is there an API or some material on how to implement handwriting recognition to webapp ? As in like you write with stylus and it stores it as font.
It would be awesome if someone has good reading materials on developing ocd webapps.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/ is the best open source tool, is it's a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

MyScript Web Components leverage Polymer project components and MyScriptJS, an open source library that speeds up the development of handwriting interfaces for web applications. MyScriptJS supports common tasks involved in implementing the handwriting user interface, including ink capture, rendering, and requests to the MyScript Cloud recognition service. MyScriptJS also manages API calls, using HTTP/REST or WebSocket protocols. Check it out on http://myscriptwebcomponents.github.io/